# Unable to open VLC media Player

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel, vlc, 23.04

I'm getting this error, when I tried to open VLC Media Player via terminal:

```bash
Driver does not support the 0x46a8 PCI ID.
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d)
[000055c08a393a00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 205)
[1]    74265 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vlc
```

I'm using freshly installed Ubuntu 23.04 with device configuration:

```
Processor: Intel 1235U
Graphics: Iris Xe Graphics
```

> I think there is something messed up with the driver but couldn't figure out the exact problem.

Things I tried:

1. Updating the driver via software update.
2. Added following PPA

```
ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
```

None of this works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was figuring out all the possibilities of driver issues. I found; this is happed due to outdated version of `libgl1-mesa-glx` which can easily be fixed by

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```